# Getting a single collection instead of array when performing a query with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a database like this:

```
Portal: id
User: id,portal_id
Item: id,user_id
```

I want to get all the items of the users in the portal in a single collection.

I have the id of user.

I can do this with arrays and even pure SQL, but I wonder if there is a better way:

```
$users = user::where("portal_id",Auth::user()->portal_id)->get();

$i = 0;

foreach($users as $user){
$items[$i] = item::where("user_id",$user->id)->get();
$i++
}
```

I want everything in the same collection instead of an array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you set up relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define [`belongsTo()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship between `Item` and `User`:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to filter items:

```
Item::whereHas('user', function ($) {
    $q->where("portal_id", auth()->user()->portal_id);
})->get();
```